# using java to open an URL in the same browser

Tags: java, browser

I met a problem about opening a link in the *SAME* Browser.

I want to open an URL in a new page in the same browser which I have already launched. Actually, I found the following code.

```
public static void runBroswer(String webSite) {
    try {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()
                && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            URI uri = new URI(webSite);
            desktop.browse(uri);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this block of code is trying to open a default browser but not the current running browser. According to browser's session problem, I must open an URL in a new page in the same browser which I have already launched. How could I do? how to use java to check which browser is being launched already?

Many thanks

Comment: Whre does the `Desktop` class come from?

Comment: java.awt.Desktop

The Desktop class allows a Java application to launch associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a file.

Comment: Desktop.browse only use the default browser. If you want to open the different one, then execute an open command within java: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("firefox  -new-tab www.google.com");

Comment: Is this from an Applet or from an Application?